# PHP MySQLi prepared statement getting row, but not displaying data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to fetch some data using an ID from another database value. Here is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT id,uid,product,jpgID,saledatetime,quantity 
                FROM sales 
             WHERE printed = ? 
                AND DATE_FORMAT(saledatetime, '%Y/%m/%d') = ?";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
        $printed = 0;
        $stmt->bind_param("is",$printed,$session_date);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        //Get result
        $stmt->bind_result($result_id,$result_uid,$result_product,$result_jpgID,$result_saledatetime,$result_quantity);

        //Number of rows returned
        $count_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
        if ($stmt_fetch = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT jpg,udate,imageset FROM images WHERE id = ?")) {
            //Fetch image information
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                $stmt_fetch->bind_param('i',$result_jpgID);
                $stmt_fetch->execute();
                $stmt_fetch->store_result();
                $stmt_fetch->bind_result($jpg,$udate,$imageset);
                echo $stmt_fetch->num_rows."<br />";

                //Create array's with information
                $print[$result_product][$result_jpgID]["quantity"] = $result_quantity;
                $print[$result_product][$result_jpgID]["location"] = $jpg;
            }
        }
        $stmt->close();
        print_r($print);
    }
```

The `echo $stmt_fetch->num_rows."<br />";` displays 1 each time it loops, so it has found a matching row. But for some reason none of the binded variables have any value... Here is the result displayed:

```
1
1
1
Array
(
    [KR] => Array
        (
            [137] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [location] => 
                )

            [138] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [location] => 
                )

        )

    [LR] => Array
        (
            [138] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [location] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: and you are absolutely sure that your second query, which looks up the jpg,udate,imageset actually works with the IDs provided when run manually? ie. in phpmyadmin or console ? Also, wouldn't it be easier to just do a join on the original query (which I don't even know) and then just loop over a single resultset instead of combining 2 this way

Comment: @Tularis, hmm it doesn't run if I define the ID manually.. :S And this is the only way I know of doing this, how would I go about combining these querys?

Comment: Also added the first query.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it, here is my fixed code.

```
if(login_check($mysqli) == true) {
    //logged in
    $session_date = $_SESSION['session_date'];

    $query = "SELECT id,uid,product,jpgID,saledatetime,quantity 
                FROM sales
             WHERE printed = ? 
                AND DATE_FORMAT(saledatetime, '%Y/%m/%d') = ?";
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
        $printed = 0;
        $stmt->bind_param("is",$printed,$session_date);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($result_id,$result_uid,$result_product,$result_jpgID,$result_saledatetime,$result_quantity);
        $count_rows = $stmt->num_rows;

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            //Create array's with information
            $print[$result_product][$result_jpgID]["quantity"] = $result_quantity;
        }
        $stmt->close();

        foreach ($print as $key1 => $value1) {
            foreach ($print[$key1] as $key => $value) {
                if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT jpg,udate,imageset FROM images WHERE id = ?")) {
                $stmt->bind_param('i',$key);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->store_result();
                    $stmt->bind_result($jpg,$udate,$imageset);
                }
                while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                    $print[$key1][$key]['location'] = $jpg;
                }
            }
        }
        print_r($print);
    }
} else {
    header("Location: index.php");  
}
```